# How can I suggest a template file specific for a content type?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

In Drupal 8, is there a way to get html.html.twig to only show on a content type like html--blog.html.twig? The suggestions in the debug don't seem to give me that option.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--node--1222.html.twig
   * html--node--%.html.twig
   * html--node.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: You would have to add the template suggestion yourself via hook_preprocess_html and some logic

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a theme suggestions alter hook:

```
/**
 * Implements THEME_theme_suggestions_html_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_html_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {

  // Check to see if you are on a node.
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {

    // Get the node type.
    $type = $node->getType();

    // Create the theme hook suggestions.
    $suggestions[] = 'html__' . $type;
    $suggestions[] = 'html__node_' . $type;
  }
}
```

Of course, change "MYTHEME to your theme name. I tested this on a blog content type for example and the new template suggestions printed out after creating this hook and clearing cache.

```
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'html' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--node-blog.html.twig
   * html--blog.html.twig
   * html--node--15.html.twig
   * html--node--%.html.twig
   * html--node.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
```

The new theme hooks here are:

```
  * html--node-blog.html.twig
  * html--blog.html.twig
```

The content type name will change accordingly in the naming suggestion.

To test, I copied `html.html.twig` and named as `html--node-blog.html.twig` and it worked great.